# SELECT with substring in ON clause?

Tags: select, substring, abap, opensql

I have the following select statement in ABAP:

```
SELECT munic~mandt VREFER BIS AB ZZELECDATE ZZCERTDATE CONSYEAR ZDIMO ZZONE_M ZZONE_T USAGE_M USAGE_T M2MC M2MT M2RET EXEMPTMCMT EXEMPRET CHARGEMCMT
INTO corresponding fields of table GT_INSTMUNIC_F
FROM ZCI00_INSTMUNIC AS MUNIC
INNER JOIN EVER AS EV on
  MUNIC~POD = EV~VREFER(9).
"where EV~BSTATUS = '14' or EV~BSTATUS = '32'.
```

My problem with the above statement is that does not recognize the substring/offset operation on the 'ON' clause. If i remove the '(9) then
it recognizes the field, otherwise it gives error:

Field ev~refer is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables 
nor defined by a "DATA" statement. I have also tried doing something similar in the 'Where' clause, receiving a similar error:

```
LOOP AT gt_instmunic.

 clear wa_gt_instmunic_f.

 wa_gt_instmunic_f-mandt = gt_instmunic-mandt.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-bis = gt_instmunic-bis.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-ab = gt_instmunic-ab.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-zzelecdate = gt_instmunic-zzelecdate.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-ZZCERTDATE = gt_instmunic-ZZCERTDATE.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-CONSYEAR = gt_instmunic-CONSYEAR.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-ZDIMO = gt_instmunic-ZDIMO.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-ZZONE_M = gt_instmunic-ZZONE_M.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-ZZONE_T = gt_instmunic-ZZONE_T.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-USAGE_M = gt_instmunic-USAGE_M.
 wa_gt_instmunic_f-USAGE_T = gt_instmunic-USAGE_T.

 temp_pod = gt_instmunic-pod.

  SELECT vrefer
  FROM ever
    INTO wa_gt_instmunic_f-vrefer
    WHERE ( vrefer(9) LIKE temp_pod  ).            " PROBLEM WITH SUBSTRING
    "AND ( BSTATUS = '14' OR BSTATUS = '32' ).
  ENDSELECT.

  WRITE: / sy-dbcnt.
  WRITE: / 'wa is: ', wa_gt_instmunic_f.
  WRITE: / 'wa-ever is: ', wa_gt_instmunic_f-vrefer.
  APPEND wa_gt_instmunic_f TO gt_instmunic_f.
  WRITE: / wa_gt_instmunic_f-vrefer.
ENDLOOP.

itab_size = lines( gt_instmunic_f ).
WRITE: / 'Internal table populated with', itab_size, ' lines'.
```

The basic task i want to implement is to modify a specific field on one table, 
pulling values from another. They have a common field ( pod = vrefer(9) ). Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: vwegert suggestion (to merge both tables manually) sounds better than any SQL dirty trick.
Besides, are you sure about your requirements or your approach to them? I fear that use a partial field to link data is dangerous... what if you have two contracts with the same 9 initial positions? How do you plan to decide which one is the right one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`field(9)` is a subset operation that is processed by the ABAP environment and can not be translated into a database-level SQL statement (at least not at the moment, but I'd be surprised if it ever will be). Your best bet is either to select the datasets separately and merge them manually (if both are approximately equally large) or pre-select one and use a FAE/IN clause.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a late enough NetWeaver version, it works on 7.51, you can use the OpenSQL function `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING`. Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT munic~mandt VREFER BIS AB ZZELECDATE ZZCERTDATE CONSYEAR ZDIMO ZZONE_M ZZONE_T USAGE_M USAGE_T M2MC M2MT M2RET EXEMPTMCMT EXEMPRET CHARGEMCMT
  FROM ZCI00_INSTMUNIC AS MUNIC
  INNER JOIN ever AS ev 
          ON MUNIC~POD EQ LEFT( EV~VREFER, 9 )
  INTO corresponding fields of table GT_INSTMUNIC_F.
```

Note that the `INTO` clause needs to move to the end of the command as well.

Answer (score -1):

> They have a common field ( pod = vrefer(9) )

This is a wrong assumption, because they both are not fields, but a field an other thing.

**If you really need to do that task through SQL,** I'll suggest you to check native SQL sentences like SUBSTRING and check if you can manage to use them within an EXEC_SQL or (better) the CL_SQL* classes.

Comment: Do not use Native SQL for application-level programming. EVER.

Comment: I try to not if I can find another approach, but the OP has asked about an SQL option.
BTW, you could explain us why to not use Native SQL EVER... it will help us to improve our knowledge, and it will make your comment appear less rude.
I edited the answer to make you a bit less grumpy ;)

Comment: Answering myself: the OP has not asked for an SQL approach: my fault.
And my apologies for the "grumpy" comment, I'll leave there for my shame (although to explain the reasons for your "EVER" is still a good thing)

Comment: ABAP uses OpenSQL to convert the SELECT statement to db-specif queries. By using Native SQL you're assuming your code will work regardless of the DB connected to the application server, which is a terribly dangerous assumption to make

Comment: And I knew it, and because that I almost never use it. But admit these two lines you kindly posted here would be a nice addition to vwegert "advice" ;)

Comment: Is it really that dangerous of an assumption to make?  Unless you are building bolt-on code, I have never been at a company that changed DB platforms.  Even today, the primary ones you hear about are AnyDB to HANA.  There are plenty of tools to tell you what needs to change in the leadup to your HANA conversion.  Is it best practice?  No, but "terribly dangerous" and "do not use... EVER" are slightly over the top, I think.

Comment: @BryanCain "I have never been at a company that changed DB platforms". Well, I have been at a bank that changed from IBM DB2 to Oracle and this bank used SAP at that time.

Comment: @Jagger - I didn't mean to suggest it never happens - only that it's fairly infrequent.  The likelihood of it happening needs to be weighed against the value from using the features you need in the Native SQL call that are not available in Open SQL.